# How to get user_id inside a controller function?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, apiato

I am developing some crud API's in an Apiato framework and it's connected to my database also,now i want to develop one api which is used for posting details to my database (valid user only can post that data) for this i want to get that user id inside an upload function i am not getting that user id How to get that id please help me to fix this issue..

`error i am getting when i try to send request in postman`

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `blogs_table` (`name`, `price`, `image`, `rating`, `country`, `description`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (maldives, 9400, ssssssssssss, 5, india, wwwwwwwwww, ?, 2021-08-09 12:22:58, 2021-08-09 12:22:58)) in file /home/vagrant/code/apiato/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 692
```

`BlogModel.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\Models;

use App\Ship\Parents\Models\Model;

class BlogModel extends Model
{
    protected $table='blogs_table';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','price','image','country','rating','description','user_id'
    ];

    protected $attributes = [

    ];

    protected $hidden = [

    ];

    protected $casts = [

    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    /**
     * A resource key to be used in the serialized responses.
     */
    protected string $resourceKey = 'BlogModel';
    public function user(){
         return $this->belongsTo(UserContainer::class);
        //return $this->belongsTo('C:\apiato-project\apiato\app\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\Models\UserContainer.php','user_id');
    }
}
```

`UserContainer.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\Models;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use App\Ship\Parents\Models\Model;

class UserContainer extends Model implements JWTSubject
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'fullName',
        'email',
        'password',
        'mobile'
    ];

    protected $attributes = [

    ];

    protected $hidden = [

    ];

    protected $casts = [

    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    /**
     * A resource key to be used in the serialized responses.
     */
    protected string $resourceKey = 'UserContainer';
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
    public function blogs(){
         return $this->hasMany(BlogModel::class, 'user_id');
       // return $this->hasMany('C:\apiato-project\apiato\app\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\Models\BlogModel','user_id');
    }
}
```

`BlogController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\UI\API\Controllers;

use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\UI\API\Requests\CreateUserContainerRequest;
use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\UI\API\Requests\DeleteUserContainerRequest;
use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\UI\API\Requests\GetAllUserContainersRequest;
use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\UI\API\Requests\FindUserContainerByIdRequest;
use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\UI\API\Requests\UpdateUserContainerRequest;
use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\UI\API\Transformers\UserContainerTransformer;
use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\Actions\CreateUserContainerAction;
use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\Actions\FindUserContainerByIdAction;
use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\Actions\GetAllUserContainersAction;
use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\Actions\UpdateUserContainerAction;
use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\Actions\DeleteUserContainerAction;
use App\Ship\Parents\Controllers\ApiController;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Containers\UserRegistration\UserContainer\Models\BlogModel;

class BlogController extends ApiController
{
    
    public function upload(Request $request ){
        //dd($request->all());
        $blog = new BlogModel();
        $blog->name=$request->input('name');
        $blog->price=$request->input('price');
        $blog->image=$request->input('image');
        $blog->rating=$request->input('rating');
        $blog->country=$request->input('country');
        $blog->description=$request->input('description');
        $blog->user_id = auth()->id();    
        $blog->save();
        return response()->json(['success'=>'successfully added','blogs'=>$blog]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: use Auth class, and in foriegn key relationships i am taking off the the hardcoded path but  both ways rae not working

Comment: What does `auth()->id()` return?

Comment: @NicoHaase, it's returning null value

Comment: if Auth::user()->id; is null then you are not passing a bearer token or user credentials to your API endpoints or using the proper middleware.  If you are using Sanctum this video will help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MT-GJQIY3EU

Comment: @Cameron, Actually i am passing the Bearer token in the headres, i am using JWT Authentication

Comment: @DevopsTraining make sure you are using the auth:api middleware on the route in question, otherwise it will not know how to use your bearer token to get user info. (if using passport)  if using sanctum watch the video I posted above on what middleware to use.   Basically you need to get it so Auth::user()  returns from your api route before anything.  if its null as you said then something isnt set up properly in your middleware or routes.

Answer (score -2):

Use Auth in you controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth
```

Try

```
$blog->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
```

Or

```
$blog->user_id = Auth::id();
```

Comment: @S N Sharma, it's not taking user id

Comment: What are you using for Auth for your API?   Sanctum? Passport?  Is the route protected by the auth or auth:api middleware?     are you using a bearer token to confirm you are a user who can post?